# Opencv video feed stops on the first frame

Tags: android, opencv, video, webcam

I'm trying to get a video feed through camera of my android phone using IP webcam and opencv.I'm using python 3.5(anaconda distribution) with opencv 3.1.0 Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.open('http://192.168.1.4:8080/video')
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('RGB output', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Problem is that when I run the script, I can only see the first frame rather than the constant video feed. I've searched alot but couldn't find a solution. Help!

Comment: problem: if you press any key you will break. but since you have waitKey (0) you'll have to press a key. So change to sth. like if waitkey (0)  == 'q' to only stop when q is pressed or change to if waitKey(10) to not wait for a keypress but stream continuously and only cancel on keyPress

Comment: What a silly mistake by me!  It now works flawlessly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.open('http://192.168.1.4:8080/video')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('RGB output', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1):
    if key == ('c'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try the above code it will be just fine..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context to this answer and fix the formatting.

Comment: Yes but it is helpful to state the general principle,  waitKey(0) as in the OP code is an infinite wait or wait unitl a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    success,frame=cap.read()  
    if(success):
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("Image",gray)
    
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('z'):
        break
        
        
        
cap.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**cv2.waitKey(0)** **is the reason you have to set it to 1** **if you want to close The Window from the existing button leave your code as it is** but without 0 to give time to CPU to process since it Video.

Notice, **You have to add & 0xFF** To Avoid other problems occurring if your  NumLock is activated.

More Here
[What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1)

**This Code Above is the Best Practice**