# What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?

Tags: python, opencv, hex

I'm trying understand what 0xFF does under the hood in the following code snippet:

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking what it is?  E.g. the value 255?  Or are you asking why it's being compared to `ord('q')`?

Comment: Maybe OP is asking why it's necessary to apply a mask at all...

Comment: Have a look here... the upper byte may contain modifier keys http://stackoverflow.com/a/33555071/2836621

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase. There is this waitkey in OpenCV which basically waits for a key and does something. Waitkey 'q' basically shuts the camera window. What I didn't understand was the purpose of 0xFF in this case. I do know it's a hexadecimal, but why do we need it?

Comment: **note to everyone:** OpenCV's behavior has changed in **December 2016** and makes this operation redundant. `waitKey` itself does this internally. this pattern is wrong now and if you see it taught, you're following bad advice.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`0xFF` is a hexadecimal constant which is `11111111` in binary.  By using bitwise AND (`&`) with this constant, it leaves only the last 8 bits of the original (in this case, whatever `cv2.waitKey(0)` is).

Comment: would that not be 10000000 in binary, so 2 to the 8th (=256)? Also I'm not sure about what you meant. I have waitkey to do a certian event by getting a key input. You get a key input, convert it into ASCII and do something with it..It seems like always when using waitkey in opencv you would use 0xFF, which I don't get.

Comment: @Dora I'm a little late here, but 0xFF is 255. F == 15 (like how we have 10 numbers, but 9 is the highest), so 15*16 + 15 == 255. 0xF == 0b1111 (15), and 0xFF == 0b1111111

Answer (score 121):

It is also important to note that ord('q') can return different numbers if you have NumLock activated (maybe it is also happening with other keys). 
For example, when pressing c, the code:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(10) 
print(key)
```

returns

```
 1048675 when NumLock is activated 
 99 otherwise
```

Converting these 2 numbers to binary we can see:

```
1048675 = 100000000000001100011
99 = 1100011
```

As we can see, the last byte is identical. Then it is necessary to take just this last byte as the rest is caused because of the state of NumLock. Thus, we perform:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(33) & 0b11111111  
# 0b11111111 is equivalent to 0xFF
```

and the value of key will remain the same and now we can compare it with any key we would like such as your question

```
if key == ord('q'):
```

Comment: wow that's a grate explanation..
first i thought why NumKeys related to opencv, at the end, it is understood..

Comment: this has stopped being true in **December 2016**. since then, waitKey always returns only the lowest 8 bits, so the masking is *redundant* (stop doing it). to get extended information (e.g. to get arrow keys), you now have to use waitKeyEx.

Answer (score 63):

cv2.waitKey() returns a 32 Bit integer value (might be dependent on the platform). The key input is in ASCII which is an 8 Bit integer value. So you only care about these 8 bits and want all other bits to be 0. This you can achieve with:

```
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 17):

In this code,

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

The `waitKey(0)` function returns **-1** when no input is made whatsoever. As soon the event occurs *i.e. a Button is pressed* it returns a **32-bit integer**.

The `0xFF` in this scenario is representing binary **11111111** a **8 bit** binary, since we only require 8 bits to represent a character we AND `waitKey(0)` to `0xFF`. As a result, an integer is obtained below 255.

`ord(char)` returns the ASCII value of the character which would be again maximum 255.

Hence by comparing the integer to the `ord(char)` value, we can check for a key pressed event and break the loop.

Answer (score 14):

> **READ THIS IT WILL SAVE YOUR TIME **

**Note 1:**
cv2.waitKey() will return the keyword that you press
in case if u just click on the close button
when the window is opened then it will return -1

**Note 2:**
let us assume that you have pressed 'q'
then cv2.waitkey() will return that 'q'
but the format it returns will be in
string data type in order to change
it to binary we are performing
bitwise AND operation with help of & symbol  with 0xFF .
0xFF  is in hexadecimal format also know
as hexadecimal constant
which is 255 in decimal format or 11111111 in binary format.

```
    Decimal=255
    Binary=11111111
    Hexadecimal=0xff
```

```
**Note it is the same value in different formats **
```

**Note 3:**
we all know that '&' in python is used to
perform bitwise 'And' operation,
**Bitwise in the sense we perform
the And operation at binary level**
**AND operation logic:**
**

```
        0&0=0
        0&1=0
        1&0=0
        1&1=1
```

**

Below represents the small table of asci value and binary value of letter 'q'

```
**Letter    ASCII Code  Binary  **
  q           113      01110001
```

**Note 4**: since we have given the
hexadecimal constant **0xFF**
whose value in binary is 11111111
let's perform the bit AND OPERATION with
the binary value of letter 'q' which
is  01110001.

```
        q= 01110001
      0xFF=11111111
          ----------
           01110001   ----->q so when do bitwise and operation we get the same value of q
          ----------
```

**Note 5:**

Since we are performing bitwise And operation
with 0xFF which is a hexadecimal constant,
once the bitwise operation is completed or
performed, the result will change to the decimal format,
so since we are using ord('q') function which will
return the decimal value or ASCII value of 'q'
so both will be equal the condition
if condition becomes true and the loop will break

Comment: "the result will change to the decimal format" is ***not*** how this works.

Answer (score 14):

The behavior of `waitKey` [has changed in v3.2 (December 2016)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/4e7b5214387e74b8df1c847d64b68e4bb3876d91).

The **current** behavior is this:

- `waitKey` returns `-1` or the lowest 8 bits of the keycode
- `waitKeyEx` returns `-1` or the *full* keycode, which can contain additional flags for special keys (e.g. arrow keys, modifiers, ...)

You **do not need** the `& 0xFF` stuff with `waitKey`. It's even **harmful** because with the masking, you can no longer test for `-1` (no key event). It becomes indistinguishable from whatever key might be encoded as 0xFF.

**Just use**

```py
if cv2.waitKey(...) == ord('q'):
    ...
```

This checks if the key `q` was pressed. `ord()` converts the string/character `q` into its ASCII integer code. That is needed because `waitKey` returns an integer.

The **historical** behavior was that there was only `waitKey`, no `waitKeyEx`. `waitKey` returned the full keycode.

If the keycode contained additional flags, it wouldn't be exactly `ord('q')` anymore. The `& 0xFF` is a bitwise operation that amounts to a mask. Only the bottom eight bits of the keycode remain, hence discarding any flags in higher bits. The comparison would succeed if you pressed the `q` key, even if any flags were set.

Answer (score 13):

Truthfully in this case you don't need 0xFF. If you did `cv2.waitkey(0) == ord(q)` it would work all the same. `0xFF` is just used to mask off the last `8bits` of the sequence and the ord() of any english keyboard character will not be greater than 255. You can reference this [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to find the numerical values of any keyboard character.

Answer (score 3):

**ord(c)** returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character(c) when the argument is a unicode object, or value of the byte when argument is an 8-bit string.

In case of 64-bit systems the value of **cv2.waitKey(0)** is bitwise AND(&) with the **0xFF** hexadecimal constant (which is representation of binary string *11111111*) that results in the last 8 bits of it. Thus checking eqality with ord(c).

Comment: this has nothing to do with unicode

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.waitKey()` returns the value -1 if no key is pressed. When you press a key, it returns the ASCII value of that key. So if you do

```
 k = cv2.waitKey(0)
 if k == ord('b'):
    break
```

when the `b` key is pressed, the value of `k` will be 98 which is equal to the value of `ord('b')`, ie 98 and this conditional will be true resulting in break.
However, depending on the platform or a keyboard modifier, a 32bit integer value will be returned. In this case, it is better to use `cv2.waitKey() & 0xFF`, which, in a binary AND operation, will result in the value of the key pressed, and can be compared with `ord('key')`

Comment: this behavior has existed before v3.2 and has no relevance today. `waitKey` always returns -1 or an 8 bit value. `waitKeyEx` returns the full code.

Answer (score 0):

cv2.waitKey() is the function which bind your code with keyboard and any thing you type will be returned by this function.
output from waitKey is then logically AND with 0xFF so that last 8 bits can be accessed.
Therefore last 8 bit represent input from keyboard and this is compared using == with the character you want.

Answer (score -1):

It's like if you waited for 0 milliseconds and press 'Q' on the key bord then the loop will break.

```
# If we've waited at least 1 ms And we've pressed the Esc
while True:
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
      break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -2):

1. `cv2.waitKey(0)` -- 0 means that what ever is your output will stay on screen for 0ms i.e infinite time period
2. `0xFF == ord('q')` -- means taking keyboard input. here its `'q'`

in normal term i say this is trying to say keep output open until user press `'q'` in its keyboard.