# OpenCV waitKey() & 0xFF

Tags: opencv

I have seen in [THIS](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html#gsc.tab=0) openCV example that they use

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
```

to check if the user pressed the character 'q'

Why are they doing the `& 0xFF` part?

If you have a bit `x` and you do `x AND 1` the bit remains the same. So doing an `AND` to all ones (0xFF) would keep the result the same.

Why is it done then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35372700/2836621

Comment: if you can imagine 0xff as 0x00ff, you'll see, that it masks out the lower 8bit (ascii) nibble from a possible 16bit scankey value. (you get the latter on some os/gui combination)

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1)