# Palette using Open CV in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ipython, color-palette

Using OpenCv I tried to do a simple color-palette by getting RGB values from User. I created a black image using numpy and changed the whole image with user entered BGR values and tried to display it.Unfortunately Python and Ipython stops responding

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

while(1):

    #Getting RGB values from user

    r=int(input("Enter R value"))
    g=int(input("Enter G value"))
    b=int(input("Enter B value"))

    #Making a Black image
    img=np.zeros((520,520,3),np.uint8)

    #Changing whole image with user defined RGB values
    img[:]=[b,g,r]

    #Making the Image to display
    cv2.imshow("Pallete",img)

    #Breaking the process while pressing ESC key
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF
    if(key==27):
        break

    #My IPython Window is not Responding and gets strucked
```

Comment: OpenCV displays don't work very well with Jupyter/IPython. Instead, I'd suggest using Matplotlib to show the images. Note that Matplotlib displays images in RGB, not BGR order.

Comment: It did work for previous python codes but struggles to open only for this program. That's my problem. Is there any error in code? or changes needed? @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: `waitKey(1)` will draw the image and the loop will start over again and it gives you a tiny 1ms window to press the key stroke before it decides to move on. Use a longer time. Just use `waitKey(0)` to wait indefinitely for a key-press.

Comment: WhoohoooYeah! That works a lot prettier. Thanks :)

Comment: But my key value always holds value 255 eventhough I press different keys ! why?

Comment: That's a different question. First, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1). Then, post your code that is giving you a result of 255 with every key press.

Comment: I know that 'cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord(any_key)' will waits for the particular key to press and do the following operations. But my question is the value stored in the variable is 255 always!

Comment: key=cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF   
    print('key:',key)   
    if(key in range(0,127)): break

Comment: I don't know, it could be something with Jupyter. Try removing the bitwise operation. Otherwise maybe you can just use `waitKey(0)` and not store it and check?