# Dynamically draw circle using mouse in openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to make an OpenCV-Py program to draw rectangle, line, and circle on mouse click and drag. I could successfully do it for line and rectangle but the code for the circle is wrong and I need help with that.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math
drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
ix,iy = -1,-1
# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y
    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
             k = cv.waitKey(33)

             if k == ord('r'):
                cv.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
             elif k==ord('c'):
                cv.circle(img,int(((ix+x)/2,(iy+y)/2)),int(math.sqrt( ((ix-x)**2)+((iy-y)**2) )),(0,0,255),-1)
             elif k== ord('l'):
                cv.line(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(255,0,0),5)
    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv.namedWindow('image')
cv.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)
while(1):
    cv.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
    break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

> ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "mouse.py", line 19, in draw_circle
>       cv.circle(img,int(((ix+x)/2,(iy+y)/2)),int(math.sqrt( ((ix-x)**2)+((iy-y)**2) )),(0,0,255),-1)
>   TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: try (int((ix+x)/2), int((iy+y)/2)) instead of int(((ix+x)/2,(iy+y)/2))

Comment: Thanks :) It worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to draw the circle dynamically.
As you drag the mouse you can see the size of the circle dynamically change.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cv.namedWindow('image', cv.WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO)
drawing = False  # true if mouse is pressed
 # Coordinate
x1, y1, x2, y2 = -1, -1, -1, -1


def run():
    img = cv.imread(f'image/python.png')        
    cv.imshow('image', img)
    # Create a layer to draw circle. The layer has the same dimension of image
    layer = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype="uint8")

   # mouse callback function
   def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
      global x1, y1, x2, y2, drawing
      # Manage different button state
      if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
          drawing = True
          x1, y1 = x, y
      elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
          if drawing == True:
              # Fill all value to 0 to clean layer
              layer.fill(0)
              cv.circle(layer, (x1, y1),calc_radius(x1, y1, x, y), (255, 0, 0), 1)
              # Create a mask of shape
              img2gray = cv.cvtColor(layer, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
              ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
              # Create a copy of original image
              _img = img.copy()
              # Set the value of mask to 0, to avoid color overlap problems
              _img[np.where(mask)] = 0
              cv.imshow('image', np.where(layer == 0, _img, layer))
      elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
          drawing = False
          layer.fill(0)
          cv.circle(layer, (x1, y1), calc_radius(x1, y1, x, y), (255, 0, 0), 1)
          # Create a mask of shape
          img2gray = cv.cvtColor(layer, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
          ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
          _img = img.copy()
          # Set the value of mask to 0, to avoid color overlap problems
          _img[np.where(mask)] = 0
          # Merge two array using Numpy where function
          cv.imshow('image', np.where(layer == 0, _img, layer))
  # Assig callback 
  cv.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

 # Service function to calculate radius (Pythagorean theorem) 
  def calc_radius(x1, y1, x2, y2):
      delta_x = abs(x2 - x1)
      delta_y = abs(y2 - y1)
      return int(math.sqrt((delta_x**2)+(delta_y**2)))

  while True:
      k = cv.waitKey(1)
      if k == ord("c"):  # c to terminate a program
          cv.destroyAllWindows()
          break

if __name__ == '__main__':
   run()
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically draw a circle with OpenCV,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
ix,iy = -1,-1

# Create a function based on a CV2 Event (Left button click)
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing
    
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        # we take note of where that mouse was located
        ix,iy = x,y
        
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        drawing == True
        
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        radius = int(math.sqrt( ((ix-x)**2)+((iy-y)**2)))
        cv2.circle(img,(ix,iy),radius,(0,0,255), thickness=1)
        drawing = False

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# This names the window so we can reference it
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Connects the mouse button to our callback function
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)

    # EXPLANATION FOR THIS LINE OF CODE:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1/39201163
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
# Once script is done, its usually good practice to call this line
# It closes all windows (just in case you have multiple windows called)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```