# Interactive circle annotation on image to replicate Matlab's drawcircle function

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

In the past I haveused Matlab's drawcircle function to interactively draw a circle on an image as a method of measuring the radius of a circular feature which is very hard to extract using circle-detection algorithms.

I am trying to make the switch over to python (making use of matplotlib and cv2 etc.), but am struggling to find any way replicating this functionality.

Is this sort of interactive annotation at all possible in Python/Matplotlib/openCV/other? Or would it be better to leave this idea behind and go down the route of iteratively entering coordinates/radius into the console?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653773/dynamically-draw-circle-using-mouse-in-opencv You might also get some ideas from the OpenCV tutorial here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html

Comment: That is very close, and a great start, thanks for finding those. A great feature of the matlab function is being able to tweak the circle, but I can make it work with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.