# I am trying to build Motion Detector using openCV and python but display window is not responding when I terminate program

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, motion-detection

Here is the code for the same, have a look at it. In this, below code I am creating a Motion Detector and with this I will be recording the timings of when the various objects appeared and disappeared for which I am using dataframe.

**The issue with this is that the program executes but when the output is displayed in the form of a Window, it freezes when I try to terminate.**

```
import cv2, pandas
from datetime import datetime

first_frame = None
status_list = [None,None]
times = []
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["Start", "End"]) #Dataframe to store the time values during which object detection and movement appears.


video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)#VideoCapture object is used to record video using web cam

while True:
    #check is a bool data type, returns true if VideoCapture object is read
    check,frame = video.read()
    status = 0
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # For converting the frame color to gray scale
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)  # For converting the gray scale frame to GaussianBlur

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame = gray   # used to store the first image/frame of the video
        continue
    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)#calculates the difference between first and other frames
    thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh_delta = cv2.dilate(thresh_delta,None,iterations=0) #Provides threshold value, so if the difference is <30 it will turn to black otherwise if >30 pixels will turn to white
    (_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #Define the contour area,i.e. adding borders

    #Removing noises and shadows, any part which is greater than 1000 pixels will be converted to white
    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
            continue
        status = 1 #change in status when the object is detected
        #Creating a rectangular box around the object in frame
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)

    #list of status for every frame
    status_list.append(status)

    status_list=status_list[-2:]

    #Record datetime in a list when change occurs
    if status_list[-1]==1 and status_list[-2]==0:
        times.append(datetime.now())
    if status_list[-1]==0 and status_list[-2]==1:
        times.append(datetime.now())

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    #cv2.imshow('Capturing',gray)
    #cv2.imshow('delta',delta_frame)
    #cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh_delta)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) #changing the frame after 1 millisecond

    #Used for terminating the loop once 'q' is pressed
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(status_list)
print(times)

for i in range(0,len(times),2):
    df = df.append({"Start":times[i],"End":times[i+1]},ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("Times.csv")

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows #will be closing all the windows
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  do you run mac, windows, linux?  cv2 version? might be helpful.

Comment: I am using windows and 3.4.1 version of cv2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

For a brief explanation about what "& 0xFF" is, see: [What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1)

It is basically a bit mask that takes the portion of 'waitKey' value(32 bit) that can be compared to ASCII (8 bit).

Comment: I tried this code snippet but it did not work. Now I am not able to terminate the program by pressing 'q'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if k == 27 :        
     break
```

where k can be any ASCII code on the keyboard [ASCII code help](https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

In this case 27 is 'Esc' button.

However, the problem you're having where it is freezing, have you tried continuously pressing any button besides q? I had a similar problem when I was testing out OpenCV's tutorial code [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

but i figured it out by playing around and then realizing i needed to hold down any button besides the 'exit' button.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue bcz of this piece of code from geeksforgeeks
Please chck the last line of the code:

> > cv2.destroyAllWindows #will be closing all the windows

Add parenthesis, it shud b:

> > cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Please try this, rest looks fine
Well you can also pass a particular frame that you want to close like:

> > cv2.destroyAllWindows("frame")