# How cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q') works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

How this line works?

As I know so far, the output of `cv2.waitKey(number)` for all every `int` number is `-1`, and `0xff` is a hexadecimal number that is equals to `255` in decimal numbers.

`-1 & 0xff` is equals to `255` in decimal numbers.

Also, `ord('q')` is equal to `113`.

But now, I don't know why `255 == 113`?

Comment: `&` is not the logical "AND" operator but the bit  operation commonly used to mask things. It means to take the first 8 bits of the `waitKey()` call and compare those to the bits of `ord("q")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

`cv2.waitKey(1)` returns the character code of the currently pressed key and -1 if no key is pressed. 
the `& 0xFF` is a binary AND operation to ensure only the single byte (ASCII) representation of the key remains as for some operating systems `cv2.waitKey(1)` will return a code that is not a single byte. `ord('q')` always returns the ASCII representation of 'q' which is 113 (0x71 in hex).

therefore if the user is pressing the q key when `cv2.waitKey(1)` is evaluated the following will be determined:

```
cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == cv2.ord('q')
0xXX71 & 0xFF == 0x71
0x71 == 0x71
True
```

Comment: On OpenCV 4.6.0, I can't find an `ord()` function in the `cv2` module, and I can't seem to find it in the documentation either. Did you mean `ord('q')` instead of `cv2.ord('q')`?

Answer (score 4):

I just finished some OpenCV code and *cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q')* was one of the pieces that I toyed with multiple times.

**First:**

*cv2.waitKey([delay])*

The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely and the delay is in milliseconds. waitKey(0) means forever.

**Second:**

The *ord()* method returns an integer representing a Unicode code point for the given Unicode character.  In your code you want the user to select the letter 'q' which is translated to the Unicode value of '113.'

**Third:**

*0xFF* is a hexadecimal constant which is 11111111 in binary. It is used to 
mask off the last 8bits of the sequence and the *ord()* of any keyboard character will not be greater than 255.

Here is the code that I'm using, which does not use *ord()* or *& 0xff*.

```
def display_facial_prediction_results(image):
  # Display image with bounding rectangles
  # and title in a window. The window
  # automatically fits to the image size.
  cv2.imshow('Facial Prediction', image)

  while (True):
    # Displays the window infinitely
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Shuts down the display window and terminates
    # the Python process when a specific key is
    # pressed on the window.
    # 27 is the esc key
    # 113 is the letter 'q'
    if key == 27 or key == 113:
        break
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: this answer is very clear and also makes the code cleaner.  I find that `waitKey(1)` works better inside the loop (for videos).  `waitKey(0)` makes the code hang.

Comment: I will have to try your suggestion for videos.  Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I am actually wondering what the advantage of `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')` is given that `key == 27 or key == 113` is shorter and cleaner ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the advantage, because they gave me problems in my environment.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is to use `waitkey(0)` instead of `waitkey(1)`

```py
from cv2 import waitkey
if waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
    break
```