# can some one explain me this part & 0xFF == ord('q') .i understand it is used to detect when q is press but what is 0xff and ord

Tags: python, opencv

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
can some one explain  me this part  & 0xFF == ord('q') .i understand it is used to detect when q is press but what is 0xff and ord

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q') works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690899/how-cv2-waitkey1-0xff-ordq-works)

Comment: The value returned by waitKey is masked such that only the least significant 8 bits are used in the comparison

Comment: @HansQ I have marked that question as a duplicate of the earlier question that I linked

Comment: @AlbertWinestein and that's been a pointless operation since 2016

Answer (score 0):

The [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function is a built-in python function that returns the unicode code point for a given character.